# A compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals

It is known that every finite space is compact. Then I am worried whether there exists a compact Hausdorff space $X$ with with ordinal of $X$ is $\omega_0$.

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "ordinal of $X$ is $\omega_0$"? Do you mean to say that [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) of $X$ is $\aleph_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Every well order with a maximum in the order topology is compact. So take any well order of cardinal $\aleph_{0}$, add a maximum if it doesn't have one and you got your space.

(Every order topology is also $T_{2}$, in fact $T_{4}$)

Comment: Sorry, but an infinite set with the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff. Two open sets always intersect.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Mingnus was talking about the order topology, not about the cofinite topology.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: My comment was posted before the edit.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I'm sorry. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set formed by the sequence {1/n} union the point {0}. This is a closed and bounded subset of the real numbers so it's compact. By definition of a sequence it's countable. It's also Hausdorff since it's a subset of a Hausdorff space (the reals).

Comment: Note that your space is Hausdorff simply because it's a subset of a Hausdorff space. The closedness is not necessary.

Comment: Made the appropriate edit. Thanks for the comment. It's compactness which requires the subset to be closed to be inherited. It's easy to forget which requirements go with which on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the following: $\Bbb N \cup \{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ is an abstract element defined by the property that $n \leq \infty \space \forall n \in \Bbb N$.